# PHP Warning:  shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in ...

Tags: cgi, shell, php, exec

В терминале выполняю следующую команду:

```
#php /var/www/test.php
```

Содержимое файла test.php:

```
shell_exec('date');
```

результат:

> PHP Warning: shell_exec() has been
> disabled for security reasons in
> /var/www/test.php on line 1

В php.ini функции отключены, а как сделать исключение конкретно для этого файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ php --help
```

> -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'

Соответственно вызывайте:

```
$ php -d disable_functions= /var/www/test.php
```

Либо сделайте этот файл исполняемым (`chmod +x /var/www/test.php`) и пропишите в нем первой строкой:

```
#!/bin/env php -d disable_functions=
```

И выполняйте его, соответственно, просто:

```
$ /var/www/test.php
```